# VBA to copy data in to column where the column header is a date selected on another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

The actual spreadsheet is slightly more involved than this, but essentially I have three worksheets:

On worksheet 1, a date is selected in cell A1.

On worksheet 2, I have a number in cell A1.

On worksheet 3, I have dates in the first row, and spaces for the numbers in the second row.

I need some VBA to copy the number in worksheet 2 and paste it in to the second row in worksheet 3, underneath the date that is selected in worksheet 1. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `hLookup` function.  It was made specifically for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CopyDateValue()
    Dim dt As Date
    dt = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value2
    Dim value As Integer
    value = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value2

    Dim dtRange As Range
    Set dtRange = Sheets("Sheet3").Rows(1).Find(dt, LookIn:=xlFormulas)

    dtRange.Offset(1, 0).Value2 = value
End Sub
```

Make sure you dim `dt` as `Date` type and stick in `xlFormulas` in the `Find` function.